# A Linux container can use an authorized_keys file outside my home directory, but ephemeral containers based on it can't. Why?

Tags: ssh, filesystem, lxc

In Ubuntu 12.10, I've created an LXC of type 'ubuntu' using the lxc-create utility. I then create ephemeral containers based on this container using the lxc-start-ephemeral utility, and I need to connect to those using password-less ssh. However, I need to keep their /home/ubuntu folders pristine, so I can't put the usual .ssh/authorized_keys file in there.

The 'encrypted home directory' section [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys) tells me how to move authorized_keys out of the home directory. After I follow those instructions from inside the base container, I can ssh into the base container without giving a password.

However, when I launch an ephemeral container from the base container, I can't ssh in without a password. (Confusingly, passwordless ssh to the ephemeral container *does* work when authorized_keys is in its usual place in /home/ubuntu/.ssh.) How can I fix this?

Here's what ssh -v said, starting from when it accepts the host key:

```
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Here are the relevant portions of /var/log/auth.log on the ephemeral container:

```
Apr 11 00:06:52 test-temp-SNeWevO sshd[306]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /
Apr 11 00:06:54 test-temp-SNeWevO sshd[306]: Accepted password for ubuntu from 10.0.3.1 port 59677 ssh2
Apr 11 00:06:54 test-temp-SNeWevO sshd[306]: pam_env(sshd:setcred): Unable to open env file: /etc/default/locale: No such file or directory
Apr 11 00:06:54 test-temp-SNeWevO sshd[306]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ubuntu by (uid=0)
```

I did this test on a fresh AWS micro instance based on the standard Ubuntu 12.10 AMI, and can provide detailed instructions on how to reproduce it if that helps.

Comment: Update: I thought the issue might be the weird filesystems lxc-start-ephemeral uses, so I made some changes. I first stopped OVERLAY_DIR and EPHEMERAL_BIND_DIR from being tmpfs's, now they're just directories. That didn't fix it. I then changed the ephemeral container's root filesystem from an overlayfs to a simple bind mount. That _did_ fix it. Unfortunately that doesn't solve my problem, because I need the overlayfs.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but it still comes up in google...

```
Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /
```

is caused by the sshd service having strict permissions requirements for the directory in which authorized_keys is found, not sure how you managed to make that the root directory (/) presumably something to do with the way your configuring containers.

If you cant change the permissions of / , which seems likely in this case, you can set

```
StrictModes no
```

in sshd_config.
Provided you don't have multiple users accessing the server, doing this has little impact to security.